# Is there a way of submitting this form after using the preventDefault function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I am trying to check for selection in form, if selected option is cash, it submits else it calls an API and onse success response is returned the form should go ahead and submit

My Javascipt

```
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', checkPayment);

        function checkPayment(event) {
            var payment = document.getElementById('payment').value;
            var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
            if (payment == "Cash") {
                alert("Paying with Cash!");
            } else {
                alert("Paying with Mpesa!");
                var valid = false;
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'payment/MpesaProcessor.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'amount': $('#parkingcharge').val(),
                        'phone': $('#phone').val(),
                    },
                    success: function(text) {
                        console.log(text);
                        if (text == "success") {
                            alert("Click Ok Once Payment Has been Received");
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $('#myform').submit();
                        } else {
                            alert("Payment Not Successful")
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use the native `submit` method of the form, it doesn't trigger the validation again.

Comment: Can you explain more please @Teemu

Comment: More? What do you want to know? Just do `$('#myform')[0].submit();` in the AJAX `success` method instead of `$('#myform').submit();`.

Comment: It still does not submit

Comment: Does it pass the condition, do you see the OK alert? Notice, that the event doesn't exist in `success` anymore, remove the line `event.preventDefault();` from it.

Comment: Yes it passes the condition

Comment: The page just refreshes, though it does not submit the form. What may I be missing?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen instead of the refresh? If the page is refreshed on submit, check the `action` attribute of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a global variable to store if AJAX call is successfull

```js
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', checkPayment);

var isSuccess = false;

function checkPayment(event) {
  var payment = document.getElementById('payment').value;
  var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  if (payment == "Cash") {
    alert("Paying with Cash!");
  } else {
    alert("Paying with Mpesa!");
    var valid = false;
    if (isSuccess) {
      return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'payment/MpesaProcessor.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        'amount': $('#parkingcharge').val(),
        'phone': $('#phone').val(),
      },
      success: function(text) {
        console.log(text);
        if (text == "success") {
          alert("Click Ok Once Payment Has been Received");
          isSuccess = true;
          $('#myform').submit();
        } else {
          alert("Payment Not Successful")
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myform">
    <select id="payment">
      <option value="Cash" >
      Cash
      </option>
      <option value="Mpesa" >
      Mpesa
      </option>
    </select>
    <input id="parkingcharge" type="number" step="any" />
    <input id="phone" />
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A quick one, whenever I add method=POST then it does not submit

Comment: Can you mention if there is any error you receive in browser console?